# Length of a curve on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a question of definition: take $(M,g)$ a riemannian manifold, $\gamma:I\rightarrow M$ a smooth path in M. We define the length of $\gamma$ as follows:
$$l(\gamma) = \int_I \vert\vert\gamma'(t)\vert\vert dt = \int_I \sqrt {g_{\gamma(t)}\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt},\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)}dt$$
My question is how is $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ interpreted as a tangent vector? I have encountered this definition problem quite a few times so I decided to ask about it.

I know that tangent vectors can be seen as equivalence classes of curves. i.e. $[\gamma]$ can act on the set of smooth functions as follows:
$$ [\gamma](f) = \frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\gamma)\vert_{t=0}$$

Is this what $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ means? I can easily show linearity but it does not seem evident to me how to show that $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ respects Leibniz's identity.

Comment: This is just the product rule for the derivative of functions of one variable.

Answer (score 1):

Any derivative respects the Leibniz rule by elementary calculus.  $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ can be viewed either as the naive tangent vector of the curve $\gamma$ or as a derivation as you described; these two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: So $\frac{d\gamma}{dt} \in T_M$ sends $f \in C^\infty(M)$ to $R$ as follows:
$\frac{d\gamma}{dt} (f) = \frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\gamma)\vert_{t = 0}$.

How do you show that this respects Leibniz?

Comment: If you let $F=f\circ\gamma$ and $ G=g\circ\gamma$ you get two ordinary functions of a real variable $t$ for which the Leibniz rule is proved in calculus. A good reference is [Keisler's *Elementary Calculus* textbook](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).